# What could cause washing machine drum to bang against housing during spin cycle after a repair?

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

I just replaced the agitator cam and cogs and drive block in my Whirlpool top loading washing machine.  I put everything back together exactly according to directions and now the outer drum seems to be banging against the metal housing.  If it was doing this before, it wasn't near this bad.  The old drive block was badly rusted and a lot of jerking had to be done to get the inner tub out.  The suspension and counter balance springs aren't broken and look alright, and the suspension pads look good as well.  Could I have stretched and ruined the springs by jerking to get the tub out?  What other things could I check?

Comment: Are there any items in the drum like clothes, shoes, rocks?

Comment: are the counter weights secure?

Comment: @wallyk  - I was washing a load of towels as a test. I adjusted the load several times on the spin cycle to try to get it to stop banging around.  The machine was not under or overloaded.  This didn't stop the banging.  Have leveled the machine also, that still doesn't help.

Comment: Does this happen with a well balanced load of clothes during a normal wash cycle, or just an empty dry run?

Comment: @Steven - thank you for mentioning counter weights.  I'll look that up and see if that is the problem.  This is my first time trying to fix a washing machine. Thank you.  I will post the outcome.

Comment: @BigHomie - well balanced load.

Comment: @Steven - where are the counter weights located?  Unable to find on appliance diagram.

Comment: @J.Hall at least on my machine, the weights are screwed onto the outside of the drum.  If they are loose, they will bang around as the drum spins

Comment: This happens when the cylinder is not properly balanced.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that one of the 3 suspension pads was indeed broken, and replaced.  Also, I had previously had to replace the drive block which was rusted out, and in trying to jerk the basket loose from it, had caused the skate plate to rest out of place.  This caused one or two of the plastic "feet" of the outer tub to be resting on top of the skate place which caused the dreadful banging against the side of the cabinet.  Once the skate plate was returned to it's proper place, and the suspension pads replaced, the washer runs smoothly once again.